# My List.Add in C# keeps adding and rewriting all previous items

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var item in tweets)
{
     XmlNode user = users[i];
     XmlNode text = texts[i];
     XmlNode id = ids[i];
     string userstr = user.InnerText;
     string textstr = text.InnerText;
     string idstr = id.InnerText;
     tweet.user = userstr;
     tweet.text = textstr;
     tweet.id = idstr;
     tweetlist.Add(tweet);
     ++i;

 }

 return tweetlist;
```

i put a break by the tweetlist.add(tweet) line so i'm sure that it is getting the correct data but everytime it adds a new item to the list it replaces the first one and adds a new one
for example

```
List{id = 1, name = "bob"} + {id = 2, name = "jenny"}
```

becomes

```
list {id = 2 name = "jenny"}, {id = 2 , name = "jenny"}
```

Comment: What are you doing with return value? If its only returning one, is there a chance its overwriting part of the original list?

Comment: You're just changing the same `tweet` and adding it to the list again.  Create a new object.

Comment: you need to understand the use of the key word `new` in regards to creating a new object..

Comment: Thanks a lot  that was the issue it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying a `tweet` object and then adding it to the list, but you never switch to a different `tweet` instance before modifying it again in the next loop, so essentially you are adding the same instance to the list again and again (remember: you add object *references*, not *copies*!) and just modify that single instance every time.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are repeatedly adding a single instance of 'tweet' and then modifying that instance, so all entries in the list will be the same. You need to create a new instance of 
tweet each time.